# Focus lost when updating a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have:

- a `JTable`, embedded in a `JScrollPane`, containing a list of items
- a `JPanel`, embedded in a `JDialog`, that displays information related to the selected item

The code works as expected (information gets updated), except that the `JTable` loses focus and the `JDialog` gets the focus every time the selection is changed. So I have added a `table.requestFocusInWindow` but the `JTable` still loses the focus, although the call returns true.

How can I make sure that the `JDialog` gets updated but that the `JTable` does not lose the focus?

ps: My end goal is to be able to browse the table with the arrows (up / down) and see the information update in the JDialog - at the moment, I need to click on the rows to do that.

**EDIT**
See below a SSCCE that replicates my issue (the content of the JDialog changes when selection is changed but the focus is lost).

```
public class TestTable extends JTable {

    public static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    public static JTextField text = new JTextField();
    public static JDialog dialog;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setResizable(false);
        showPopup();
        final JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane.getViewport().add(new TestTable());
        f.add(jScrollPane);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public TestTable() {
        super();
        setModel(new TestTableModel());
        getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
                int row = lsm.getAnchorSelectionIndex();

                Object item = getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);

                text.setText(item.toString());
                dialog.setVisible(true);
                TestTable.this.requestFocusInWindow(); //DOES NOT DO ANYTHING
            }
        });
        setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    }

    public class TestTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public TestTableModel() {
            super(new String[]{"DATA"}, 3);
            setValueAt(Double.valueOf(-0.1), 0, 0);
            setValueAt(Double.valueOf(+0.1), 1, 0);
            setValueAt(Double.valueOf(0), 2, 0);
        }
    }

    private static void showPopup() {
        dialog = new JDialog(f, "Title");
        dialog.setContentPane(text);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something in your dialog that grabs the focus on the fly, because I have tried with a JLabel and it does not cause any problem. If you need to work around this, you can always call `toFront()` on your JTable parent Frame. If it does not help your case, try to edit this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to reproduce your issue.

See this code (comment the grabFocus on the label to convince yourself that there is something in your dialog that grabs the focus):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.FocusManager;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
        private int count;

        public MyTableModel() {
            addColumn("Test");
        }

        public void insertNewRow() {
            Vector<String> rowData = createNewRowData();
            insertRow(0, rowData);
        }

        private Vector<String> createNewRowData() {
            Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>(1);
            data.add("Hello-" + count++);
            return data;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            model.insertNewRow();
        }
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, false);
        dialog.add(label);
        dialog.setSize(300, 50);
        dialog.setLocation(400, 0);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                final Component focused = FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getFocusOwner();
                int index = table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
                if (index > -1) {
                    Object valueAt = model.getValueAt(index, 0);
                    label.setText("Current row selected is: " + valueAt);
                } else {
                    label.setText("No selection");
                }
                label.grabFocus();
                if (focused != null) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            frame.toFront();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - If you have a second, I have posted a SSCCE above that replicates the issue.

Comment: @assylias yes I saw that. I just copied it and it seems that calling `f.toFront()` does the trick

Comment: Actually the main difference is that I call `dialog.setVisible()`. If I remove that line I get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Yes - I have changed the line with `if (!dialog.isVisible()) dialog.setVisible(true);` and now it works fine. Thanks for your code, it helped me spot the problem!